# How to prevent VLC player restore window when changing new song?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I got stuck in one problem so annoying.

When I play songs in VLC and work. When it changes new song, the window of VLC show as a popup, and I have to minimize it.

Anyone have idea for this?

Comment: Does it happen when you minimize to tray too (by clicking on tray icon)?

Comment: @VarunAgw: the same thing! The window on taskbar disappears, but when new song comes, the window appear again. If we currently work on other window, the window on taskbar turn to "orange color". And if the next song comes, the same thing happends.

Comment: I think the easiest fix might be to uninstall it and clean install it.

Comment: Is this Windows 10? Also what file type are the song files? .mp3?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tool>Preferences, in the interface settings set the
"Auto raising the interface" to Never.